# Gmail API Quota Limits

Tags: gmail-api

Hopefully a simple question, but with regard to the quota limits outlined here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

at what point during the HTTP lifecycle are these counted? The start of the request, the completion of the request, the completion of the response..?

As a worked example (and **ignoring** short bursts), if I have three message.send commands (300 units) whose requests all start at the same time but end at different times, would that break the 250 per user per second quota or not?

Comment: When your application send request to Google API, it consumes quota. So, each request when hits google API, counts with quota irrespective of the response from the API. Each method has its own quota.

Comment: Quota is generally two types: QPS(Quota per sec) and QPD(Quota per day). Also , per-user limit is there which counts to quota.

Comment: Thanks - to confirm, are you saying that under QPS a 3 second message.send would use 100 units for each second in the request? The reason for the question is I'm trying to multi-thread in my client but also want to pro-actively avoid "Too Many Requests" and exponential back-off.